# SDK checksum validation

Tags: ios, objective-c

Okay, this question applies to most scenarios where a vendor distributes an SDK binary to 3rd party developers to use. But for easier discussion, let's assume I am developing an iOS SDK in Objective-C, and planning to hand it to any developers who have registered on our portal.

This SDK will access our services located on our server. And since the resources on our server are limited (well, on any server actually), we have built in some simple throttling mechanism in the SDK to prevent bad use of API's, like putting a remote procedure calls in a loop which executes 10K times a second, whether purposefully or not. Anytime such a thing happens, we throw.

As long as the developers use the binary as is, things are fine. But what if someone tries to do some funny things, like breaking our throttling mechanism by changing the binary, then linking to their app? In such a case, our client throttling mechanism no longer works, and a few instances of their app running could bring our server down.

Our thought is that we can build some checksum validation mechanism in the SDK binary, then calculate the binary's checksum during runtime initialisation, and compare that to the one in the binary. If our binary is tampered with, we cancel the initialisation, and prevent the host app from using our resources.

We already have server-side throttling mechanism on the server. But we also throttle on the client, since many unthrottled requests to the server still consume resources unnecessarily on the server, even we have throttling ready on the sever.

Is that a viable thought? Anyone have experience on this matter?

Thanks!

Comment: Do the throttling on the server side instead?

Comment: We have that mechanism on the server. But we also throttle on the client, since many unthrottled requests to the server still consume resources unnecessarily on the server, even we have throttling ready on the sever.

Comment: Then I don't understand the issue.

Comment: The issue is that even our server bails out early when it sees a malicious request, it still needs to handle the request. Although it might not spend as much time due to the bailout, the total time can still sum up considerably if many malicious requests are flooding in.

Comment: Your problem is that you can't trust the client code, so therefore you can't trust any signature that the client code sends you. Why don't you log the details of clients that exceed the server threshold and "have words with them"?

Comment: Yes you are right, I can't trust the client code. Just looking to see if there is any mechanism to increase the cost of tampering with our SDK binary considerably.